# JTextField não interpreta \n como quebra de linha

Tags: java, jtextfield, quebras-de-linha

Ao imprimir os dados do cliente no JTextField, quando o `\n` está presente significa uma quebra de linha, porém em vez de passar para a linha seguinte cada vez que encontra um `\n`, ele simplesmente ignora e continua a escrever em frente.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
lista.setText(clientes[i].toString());

public String toString(){
    return String.format("\t-----------------------Cliente Regular-------------------------\n[%s]\t-> Nome: %s\n\t->Contacto: %s\n\t->NIF: %d\n\t->E-email: %s\n\t->Morada: %s\n",super.getnickname(),super.getnome(),super.getcontacto(),super.getnif(),super.getemail(),super.getmorada());
}
```

E o seu output deveria ser algo como:

```
"\t-----------------------Cliente Regular-------------------------\n
[%s]\t-> Nome: %s\n
\t->Contacto: %s\n
\t->NIF: %d\n
\t->E-email: %s\n
\t->Morada: %s\n"
```

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: Se o texto da String é escrito manualmente, não é mais fácil apagar os \n?

Comment: a imagem não dava para ver João, só quem está logado é que poderá ver. O Stack Overflow tem o seu próprio uploader de imagens por cima do editor.

Answer (score 1):

Não está atualizando corretamente, coloque duas barras em vez de uma.

Substitua de:

```
return String.format("\t-----------------------Cliente Regular-------------------------\n[%s]\t-> Nome: %s\n\t->Contacto: %s\n\t->NIF: %d\n\t->E-email: %s\n\t->Morada: %s\n",super.getnickname(),super.getnome(),super.getcontacto(),super.getnif(),super.getemail(),super.getmorada());
```

Para:

```
return String.format("\\t-----------------------Cliente Regular-------------------------\\n[%s]\t-> Nome: %s\\n\\t->Contacto: %s\\n\\t->NIF: %d\\n\\t->E-email: %s\\n\\t->Morada: %s\\n",super.getnickname(),super.getnome(),super.getcontacto(),super.getnif(),super.getemail(),super.getmorada());
```